# Having great difficulty making a popup display exactly in the center no matter where it pops up

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basically I've made a popup and I've positioned it at the top of my page, which works great, but this obviously doesn't work for the footer links at the bottom as it just shows it at the top.

I want to be able to make it pop up in the center no matter where the link is pressed, I hope this makes sense.

I've tried searching the internet not to any usful tutorials on how to fix this problem.

So I have turned to the power of Stackoverflow.

Visual: 
http://madaxedesign.co.uk/

Jquery:

```
    $('a.contact , a.contact_footer, a.contact_text').click(function() {
    $("#popup").load("contact.php");
    // Getting the variable's value from a link
    var 
    show = $('#popup').css('display', 'block'),
    popup = $(this).attr('href');

    //Fade in the Popup and add close button
    $(popup).fadeIn(300);

    //Set the center alignment padding + border
    var popMargTop = ($(popup).height() + 24) / 2; 
    var popMargLeft = ($(popup).width() + 24) / 2; 

    $(popup).css({ 
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

    // Add the mask to body
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

    return false;
});

// When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
$('a.cross, #mask').live('click', function() { 
  $('#mask , #popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
    $('#mask').remove();  
}); 
return false;
});
```

If you need more information please ask.

Comment: Have you tried using $(window).scrollTop()? I've used it for similar situations. Here's the API: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: ooooo no i haven't, that is a good little trick though. Will have a play now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some of the code that I used for this situation, I've modified it to be similar to your code:

```
var view_width = $(window).width();
var view_top = $(window).scrollTop() + 70;

// Move the lightbox to the middle of the screen.
$( popup ).css("left", (view_width - $( popup ).width() ) / 2 );
// Make sure the window is in view no matter where you are on the page
$( popup ).css("top", view_top);
```

Comment: Hmm I'm interested in making this method work but i can't seem to get it there. It doesn't fling back up to the top of the page

Comment: Are you wanting to scroll the page back up to the top and then put the popup in? I think I'm a bit confused by what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, I think i mis-understood you. I thought you this would onclick of the footer go to the top of the screen where the pop up will be displayed

Comment: Ahhh, okay. This code was designed to bring the popup to wherever your screen is at. I think you can use scrollTop() to set the page's scroll too maybe...

Comment: I think that is the way I'm going to do it though. Thanks for your help on this one.

Comment: Good job, that looks great!

Answer (score 0):

For displaying images in the center of the page or an element I use the following css code:

```
.element{position:absolute; display:block; margin:auto; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;}
```

By the way, that is the same code which firefox uses, if you view a single image-file.
I think that should also work for a popup.

Comment: I tried this and it only shows it at the top still. so just doing the same thing it is at the moment unfortunately

Comment: @Maximus To get this working, I think there hsa to be an element with `position:relative;` arround the popup, so if you've got something like an full screen element as an background behind the popup, it might work better

Comment: hmm my container has position relative on it so should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to actually display pop-up menus is by position:fixed. You can then position your menu wherever on the page and it will never move(regardless of scroll position) until you exit out. Upon closing the menu, just change it back to display:block.

Comment: The reason I didn't do this before was because it would break on phones meaning you couldn't scroll from a certain point. However I can simply change it back to absolute for anything smaller than 600px. Unless you know another way of making it work for a phone?

Comment: Well, in that case you could just use overflow:scroll, if the content was larger than the screen.